# Cfonts causing Glitch in RGB text

Tags: python

So I am trying to print RGB (Color Changing) Text and it has to come after the Big Text (using cfonts).

Big_Text:

```
from cfonts import render
from time import sleep
from os import system
import time

def Big_Text(Text, Time):

    clear = lambda: system("cls")

    x = 0
    y = 0

    color1 = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "cyan", "magenta"]
    color2 = ["blue", "magenta", "red", "yellow", "green", "cyan"]

    t_end = time.time() + Time

    Text = Text.split()

    z = 0

    Txt = ""

    while time.time() < t_end:

        clear()

        if Txt.split() != Text:

            Txt = Txt + f" {Text[z]}"

        else:

            Txt = Txt

        if x == len(color1):

            x = 0
            y = 0

        output = render(Txt, colors=[color1[x], color2[y]], align='center')
        print(output)

        if z < len(Text)-1:
        
            z += 1

        else:

            z += 0

        x += 1
        y += 1

        sleep(1)

Big_Text("Hello Fellow User", 3)
```

[Big_Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph4mS.png)

RGB_Text:

```
from time import sleep

def RGB(txt, Cycles):

    def colored(r, g, b, txt):
        return f"\033[38;2;{r};{g};{b}m{txt} \033[38;2;255;255;255m"

    r = 255
    g = 0
    b = 0
    x = 0

    while x != Cycles:

        while g != 255:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            g += 51

        while r != 0:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            r -= 51

        while b != 255:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            b += 51

        while g != 0:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            g -= 51

        while r != 255:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            r += 51

        while b != 0:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            b -= 51

        x += 1

    print(f"\033[38;2;{r};{g};{b}m{txt} \033[38;2;255;255;255m")

RGB("Hello World", 1)
```

[RGB_Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J1zy.png)

These work exactly as I want separately, but as soon as I put them together, Big_Text works fine but the RGB_Text starts Glitching

Here's how I have done it:

```
from cfonts import render
from time import sleep
from os import system
import time

def Big_Text(Text, Time):

    clear = lambda: system("cls")

    x = 0
    y = 0

    color1 = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "cyan", "magenta"]
    color2 = ["blue", "magenta", "red", "yellow", "green", "cyan"]

    t_end = time.time() + Time

    Text = Text.split()

    z = 0

    Txt = ""

    while time.time() < t_end:

        clear()

        if Txt.split() != Text:

            Txt = Txt + f" {Text[z]}"

        else:

            Txt = Txt

        if x == len(color1):

            x = 0
            y = 0

        output = render(Txt, colors=[color1[x], color2[y]], align='center')
        print(output)

        if z < len(Text)-1:
        
            z += 1

        else:

            z += 0

        x += 1
        y += 1

        sleep(1)

Big_Text("Hello Fellow User", 3)

from time import sleep

def RGB(txt, Cycles):

    def colored(r, g, b, txt):
        return f"\033[38;2;{r};{g};{b}m{txt} \033[38;2;255;255;255m"

    r = 255
    g = 0
    b = 0
    x = 0

    while x != Cycles:

        while g != 255:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            g += 51

        while r != 0:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            r -= 51

        while b != 255:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            b += 51

        while g != 0:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            g -= 51

        while r != 255:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            r += 51

        while b != 0:

            print(colored(r, g, b, txt), end="\r")
            sleep(0.1)

            b -= 51

        x += 1

    print(f"\033[38;2;{r};{g};{b}m{txt} \033[38;2;255;255;255m")

RGB("Hello World", 1)
```

[Glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho5yR.png)

This Glitch only happens when RGB_Text is printed after Big_Text. How could I fix this?